# What technologies are used in the editor of Canva

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I was wondering if anyone knew how [Canva's](https://www.canva.com/design/play?template=EAEO003Gtm4&category=tACFajEYUAM&type=TABQqs5Kbyc) editor was created. I found a similar design company and [their editor](https://desygner.com/editor/?id=qE3erIN7S02) looks identical. I figured it was built with canvas and a library like fabric or konva, but when you look at the source HTML, there is no canvas on either.

It seems odd to me that two companies would have such a similar editor. Is there a library that they are using, or is it just built with regular html elements, and they make the elements draggable? Then they create an image with a dom to image function?

I've searched the internet for guides to creating a online graphic editor, but there are none. I can't find answers anywhere else. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles upon this question, I believe I've found the answer. I think it's created using svgs. [Method Draw](https://editor.method.ac/) and [svg edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) are good examples of what it might be expanded upon to create the complexity they have achieved.

Comment: Apart from these libs, have you figured out how to create an editor? I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Same here. Looking for resources on how to create an image editor.

Comment: I was able to create a cross-platform Canva-level editor from scratch in Flutter. You can contact me and I can show you a demo